# Java.text.ParseException:Unparseable date

Tags: java

```
String input="5/31/2013 2:30:56 PM";
SimpleDateFormatter s=new SimpleDateFormatter("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a").Parse(input);
System.out.println(s);
```

I am expecting to this output "May 31,2013 2:30 PM" in this format but I am getting unparseable error if any one know the alternate way help me to resolve it.

Comment: Look at your input string and your format. They don't match.

Comment: What's `SimpleDateFormatter`? In any case, your format string doesn't match your input, so it's not clear what you expect.

Comment: There is not SimpleDateFormatter in the Java standard library - where does this class come from? Apart from that, having a method "Parse" that starts with a capital also indicates this is not part of the official Java API.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

You use incorrect format of date. Passed string has format `M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss a`

Answer (score 0):

Change `SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a")` to `SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss a")`

Comment: No such thing as `SimpleDateFormatter` in my universe!

Comment: What universe are you from? XD

Comment: @Sapikelio The one that's using standard Java libraries since no other library information was tagged or provided in the question.